# Python yield not waiting on blocking call

Tags: python, zeromq, yield, pyzmq

I have a subscriber that is blocking and when I receive a object, I yield. But even before I reach the yield, it yields. Can I approach this problem in a different way?

```
def sub():
    context = zmq.Context()
    subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    subscriber.bind("ipc:///tmp/asd")
    subscriber.subscribe(b'007')
    while True:
        [topic,msg] = subscriber.recv_multipart()
        print("here") # does not print
        p = pickle.loads(msg)
        print(p)
        yield (p.url)

def main():
    print(sub()) # Expect to wait for sub to yield

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Yields immediately: `<generator object sub at 0x7fdfcba10eb8>`

My expectation is for it wait there. Any way to achieve this?

[EDIT]

ok so `print(next(sub()))`, as yield return a generator object as expected, `next` will get the result.

Comment: Ohh, I just realized, `print(next(sub()))` is blocking.

Comment: `sub()` just creates the generator object, you haven't called next on it, none of the code in `sub` has actually executed, **it never yielded anything**

Comment: Yeah thanks. I realized like 5 seconds after posting :)